# Why image rotation animation only works correctly for the first time

Tags: android, android-animation

I have this simple arrow image rotation animation which works as intended only for the first time. from second time onward It's still do the rotation but without slow animation.

[image]

Here's the code in anim xml files

**Rotate 180**

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="180"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"/>
```

**Rotate Revere**

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromDegrees="180"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    />
```

**The image view inside card view.**

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/creadit_card_next_image"
   android:layout_width="@dimen/next_image_size" 
   android:layout_height="@dimen/next_image_size"
   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/static_menu_primary_margin"
   android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
   android:rotation="-90"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next"
   android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Java code to trigger Animation.**

```
private Animation rotatePlus180;
private Animation rotateMinus180;
private boolean creditDebitCardViewExpanded = true;

rotatePlus180 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_plus_180);
rotateMinus180 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_minus_180);



private void onClickCreditDebitCardView() {
        creditDebitCardPaymentMethod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (creditDebitCardViewExpanded) {
                    expandAnimation(paymentRecyclerView);
                    creditDebitCardViewExpanded = false;
                    creditCardNextImage.setAnimation(rotatePlus180);
                } else {
                    collapseAnimation(paymentRecyclerView);
                    creditDebitCardViewExpanded = true;
                    creditCardNextImage.setAnimation(rotateMinus180);

                    CreditDebitLayoutContainer.setPadding(0, 0, 0, padding);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where are you setting `rotatePlus/Minus180`? You may be losing those values. I can't really tell you're going to another Activity or doing something that might cause them to be lost. If you're not doing so already, try setting them in `onResume()`.

Comment: I'm assigning `rotatePlus/Minus180` in `onCreate()`. and I'm not going to another activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setAnimation use startAnimation

```
creditCardNextImage.startAnimation(rotatePlus180);
creditCardNextImage.startAnimation(rotateMinus180);
```

setAnimation seems to be called once you attach the animation to the view/ or when the view is added.

StartAnimation will be called all the time even if the view has already been added.